# Seeking Free Task and Project Organization Software for R&D Work

Tags: software-development, time-management, task-management

**Hello community,**

I am an R&D professional in search of a free software or web application to efficiently organize my individual tasks and projects. While my team utilizes collaboration tools like Jira, I am specifically looking for a personal solution to manage tasks, research topics, personal projects, learning activities, and sometimes include detailed descriptions for future reference.

**Key Requirements:**

- **Individual Use**: I am not looking to share information with colleagues. The tool should focus on personal organization.
- **Task Management**: I need to organize tasks, assign specific dates, track progress over time, and include detailed descriptions for clarity.
- **Topic Grouping**: The ability to group tasks and projects by topics is crucial for my workflow.
- **Web and Ubuntu Compatibility**: The ideal solution should be accessible through a web browser and have compatibility with Ubuntu as a software application.

I've explored various articles on free applications, but many are trial versions or come with limitations. I'm reaching out to the community for recommendations based on personal experiences. Your insights will be highly valuable in helping me find the right tool for my needs.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: I use todoist for over a year and I like it.

Comment: I started using Smartsheet at work. I believe they have a freemium business model where you may be able to get what you need without ever paying (we use the business plan for dashboarding and automation). You're able to attach files to rows and enter data in cells as categorical. When researching, I liked the UI of Monday.com more, but it seemed to be more limited.

Comment: Hi. Please mention the ones you have already tried. There are many notes/tasks apps to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem in general. I advice two mindset:

1. Keep it deadly simple
   With any note-taking app with foldering structure can help you to track of your progress, I recommend [iCloud Notes](https://www.icloud.com/notes) or [Notion](https://www.notion.so/pricing) for the beginning but you'll face upload limits with them.
2. Look for future-proof alternative
   [ClickUp](https://clickup.com/) can be a good alternative. It offers online version and Linux-distro [versions](https://clickup.com/download). Downside is the fairly higher upload limit as of today 100MB. It contains tasks, grouping your items, creating docs and sharing if you needed + whiteboard.